# Blazor Server Update all component instances

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-signalr

I have multiple components that have data being fed to them, when updated in the back end right now I have a Cascading App State to update the components when they are updated and this is working, however if I have a second browser open and I am looking at this component I don't see it updating, unless I refresh the page
I am using Blazor Server .Net 5, does anyone know how I can have all component instances update in real time?

Comment: Add some code that demonstrates your problem.  Without that we're shooting in the dark with answers,  My guess is you need to implement an event in your backend whenever you data state changes and have the components register for the event and update accordingly,  But I'm only guessing!

Comment: Singleton service with an event to subscribe to?